# Update iPod touch OS remotely

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, ipod, upgrade

I currently live in an area that has very poor internet connection. I can log in to iTunes but it would cost a fortune to download the updates to the OS. Is there a way I can have somebody bring the OS update on a thumb drive and load it from there?

Answer (score 5):

When you plug in the iPod touch, <kbd>Alt</kbd>- or <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>-click the device's "Restore" button in iTunes. This will allow you to choose the appropriate `ipsw` file to load on the device.

Have someone download the appropriate firmware for your device. Below are links to Apple's downloads of the 4.2.1 firmware.

- [iPod touch 2G firmware 4.2.1](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/061-9855.20101122.Lrft6/iPod2,1_4.2.1_8C148_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPod touch 3G firmware 4.2.1](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/061-9860.20101122.Xsde3/iPod3,1_4.2.1_8C148_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPod touch 4G firmware 4.2.1](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/061-9859.20101122.%24erft/iPod4,1_4.2.1_8C148_Restore.ipsw)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>-click (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-click if using Windows) the restore button on the iPod screen, then navigate to the IPSW file you want to use to restore.